# Solspace Super Serarch Returns No Results

Tags: solspace, search, supersearch

I am having some trouble with Solspace super search not returning results on some channels. For example

```
{exp:super_search:results limit="3" channel="getting_here"}
    <li>
        {title}
    </li>
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

And my URL that this query is on

```
/search&keywords=journey/
```

There are entries in the getting here channel with "journey" in the title.

Searches of other channels return results but this one does not.

Running ExpressionEngine v2.6.1 & Solspace Super Search v2.1.3

Comment: What is the status of your entries? If you're not using the `status=""` parameter, Super Search will look for **Open** entries only.

Comment: Status is open.

Comment: Is this code wrapped in any other code? Have you tried this code on a *completely*, *absolutely blank* EE template with *nothing whatsoever on it besides the code*? Also, are these **future entries**?

Comment: Loaded this into a blank template. With no parameters set in the URL it works so "/blank_template/" returns enteries from the channel. However as soon as /search&keywords=journey/ is added on, it does not return any results. These are not future entries and they are not wrapped in any other code.

Comment: Could it be EE not being able to read `{segment_1}` being `search&keywords=journey`? What if your search results page was on a URL such as `http://mysite.com/search/results/search&keywords=journey`?

Comment: You might have to open up a ticket at support.solspace.com so we can have a closer look at your particular situation. Please provide CP and FTP credentials. Thanks.

Comment: Ok we now have a situation where this intermitently works. When it stops working there is no error message, but if i leave it alone for fifteen minutes it will work again for a little bit. I dont believe its our server setup, is there some kind of throttling built into the search functionality?

Comment: Could it be EE not being able to read `{segment_1}` being `search&keywords=journey`? What if your search results page was on a URL such as `http://mysite.com/search/results/search&keywords=journey`? Have you cleared your EE and Super Search cache? Again, you might want to open a ticket.